# How can I determine the polarity of an unmarked dc input?

Tags: dc, polarity

I have a portable television with only a 12 volt input. The power lead is missing, which is not really a problem as long as I can identify either positive or negative. The socket is approximately 10mm x 15mms with a groove in the base, perhaps intended for use in a caravan ?
The TV is an early 1970s Rigonda and I can't find a manual !
Hope somebody can assist.
With thanks.

Comment: Note that a 1970's TV will be useless in most places on earth today: we've switched from analog to digital TV pretty much globally.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Converter boxes still exist, and you can hook it up to anything with an appropriate analog output, like a VCR, DVD player, video game console, or whatever else you care to use.

Comment: Does it have inputs of some kind? Coax, composite, audio...? You can try measuring for continuity between the ground of one of those connections and the 12V input connections.

Comment: if it's not marked, and given the vintage, I would not rule out AC. Look for continuity to ground from one of the plug's terminals, usually negative is chassis grounded.

Answer (score 4):

Pop it open and take a look at the components.  If you can find polarized capacitors or diodes (power indication LED, maybe?) connected in an obvious fashion to the inputs, you're in luck.  Otherwise you'll have to reverse-engineer the circuit until you can make a call either way.